# Runtime error on taking input into c++ array

Tags: c++, combinatorics

I'm working on a programming problem (Uva #11330 https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&category=&problem=2305&mosmsg=Submission+received+with+ID+20947216) and my code passes the test cases given but keeps giving me a runtime error when I submit and I can't figure out why. It runs perfectly fine on my end. I've narrowed the problem down to where I take in input. Any ideas as to why it's giving me that error?

[EDIT] Changed array declaration. Now the issue is that the autojudge says it's wrong even though I still pass all the test cases. Any further ideas?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;



int main(){
    int numTestCases;
    int numShoes;
    int l, r;
    int numSwaps;
    int leftIndexes[10005];
    int rightIndexes[10005];
    int leftShoes[10005];
    int rightShoes[10005];
    cin >> numTestCases;

    for(int i = 0; i < numTestCases; i++){

        numSwaps = 0;



        cin >> numShoes;

        for(int j = 0; j < numShoes; j++){
            cin >> l >> r;
            leftIndexes[l-1] = j;
            rightIndexes[r-1] = j;
            leftShoes[j] = l-1;
            rightShoes[j] = r-1;
        }

        for(int j = 0; j < numShoes; j++) {
            if(leftIndexes[j] != rightIndexes[j]) {
                int aIdx = rightIndexes[j];
                rightShoes[aIdx] = rightShoes[leftIndexes[j]];
                rightIndexes[rightShoes[leftIndexes[j]]] = aIdx;                
                numSwaps++;
                //cout << ret << endl;
            }
        }
        cout << numSwaps << endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please briefly describe the problem on the question instead of just posting a link to the problem statement (you can keep the link for further reference).

Comment: Well I knew where the problem in my code was so I didn't feel it necessary to really describe the problem.

Comment: So you know where the problem is, and you don't feel it necessary to describe the problem. Given that, what exactly do you want from _us_?

Comment: If you think the problem is in reading the input then you could include an input example. Do you get any feedback from the attempted submission?

Comment: `int leftShoes[numShoes];` This is not C++. This is an *unsafe* vendor-specific extension you should never use. Disable all language extensions in your compilation flags.

Answer (score 3):

```
cin >> numShoes;

int leftShoes[numShoes];
int rightShoes[numShoes];
int leftIndexes[numShoes];
int rightIndexes[numShoes];
```

Nope.

Array dimensions shall be *compile-time constants*. You can't size an array with user input.

Make a dynamic block of memory using `new[]`, or get yourself a nice `vector`.

Then, add error checking to all your I/O so that you know you aren't trying to access nonsense indexes in your fixed arrays/vectors.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but just as a side note, in the case of C99 you can use [variable length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), not in C++ afaik. Still, wouldn't be a good idea here.

Comment: @jdehesa: Yeah, we know about VLAs, and GCC even supports them in C++ mode as an extension - but the question is tagged C++, and when teaching tbqh I prefer to pretend they do not exist in practice, and the key point is adding error checking to the I/O so that you have not only known dimensions, but also known access indices. :)

Comment: Sure, just mentioned it as a related feature (or design mistake for some :)) that can be seen in actually valid (C99) code, for reference (btw obsessively downvoting a person with >250k rep sounds like the dumbest thing ever).

Comment: @jdehesa: (not necessarily a deal breaker for some ^_^)

Comment: Thanks! This was the issue. But now for some reason the autojudge says it's wrong even though I pass all the test cases

Comment: @user2953932: If you pass all the test cases, in what way is the code reported as "wrong"?

Comment: It won't tell us. The online judge just gives 6 outputs: Accepted, Time Limit Exceeded, Compilation Error, Runtime Error, Presentation Error or Wrong Answer. I keep getting Wrong Answer.

Comment: It's impossible to debug a program with no more information than "wrong answer". You need to compile and run this locally so you can actually see what answer is being given and step through it in a debugger to see where it's going wrong.